# Bootstrap sticky nav top shifts to bottom on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am using a bootstrap framework and I am wondering what would be the process of making my top nav become a bottom sticky nav when in mobile view? In other words, how would one turn off the .nav class but have the same .nav in the footer, only to turn on at mobile?
Would that be a process of turning off the top nav completely and then turning on the footer nav? Or can I just change some code to have the top nav shift to the bottom when a breakpoint is hit?

I tried `.navbar{ display: none; }`, but this turns off the nav when in mobile view.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Ok sorry for being so minimal, I am trying to get my main menu nav to appear at the bottom when mobile breakpoint is hit. I am using bootstrap framework, how would one turn off the .nav class but having the same .nav in the footer, only to turn on at mobile, here is what I tried: '.navbar{
  display: none;
}' but this turns off the nav when in mobile view, so I hope this better explains my issue